# AnyLogic: Store the maximum value from timeMeasureEnd in order to use optimisation

Tags: anylogic

I would like to store the maximum value from timeMeasureEnd in order to use in an optimisation problem. My goal is to minimise staff levels to make sure that the process takes no more than x minutes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the dataset, assign the maximum value to a variable and use it in the optimization experiment. Call is as timeInSystemMax, for example. Then, plug it into the requirements section of the optimization experiment:

[image]

You can use the following structure to get the maximum value from an array:
`Arrays.stream(this.timeInSystem).max().getAsDouble()`

EDIT: More details on picking the maximum.

You can use an event set to happen at the end of your simulation with the following action:

[image]

There is a dataset automatically associated with the timeMeasureEnd block. So, you can use the function to set its maximum value to a variable called `timeInSystemMax` (it should be defined in the Main); like this:
[image]

`timeInSystemMax=timeMeasureEnd.dataset.getYMax()`

Comment: Really appreciate the response, but do you mind elaborating a little as I am very new to AnyLogic. I understand the requirements part, but i'm very confused on the rest

Comment: Okay, trying to help. Can you please add more detail about your model? Do you have that maximum value only once per simulation? Or do you have that max value for each agent?

Comment: Once per simulation

Comment: Here is a picture of the model https://prnt.sc/20xoap4

Comment: Hi again. I am really appreciating your help. However, it comes up with an error that "timeInSystemMax cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Have you defined it as a variable in the Main as I have shown in one of the screenshots above??

Comment: It was a variable in the main. However, the issue I believe was not putting .root infront of it as now I am able to run the optimisation

Comment: Hi Again, sorry to keep bothering you. But my optimisation just gives me a result of 0 staff members. This is intuitively wrong but I don't understand why this is the result i'm getting?

Comment: Check your objective function and the constraints (requirements). You need to put some more requirements (say, customersServed>1000).. otherwise just minimization will give you zero